# RISC-V byte load and store

Tags: memory, instruction-set, risc-v

I have the confusion in the following RISC V programming statements. Can someone explain that why does the contents of s0 in the last comment shown. shouldn't it be 0x00000180 the same as we are not messing up contents of s0. Also the contents of s2 would be 0x00000080? since the 24 bits should be ignored. Kindly explain this as I am confused.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to instruction set manual, the comment is correct.

The byte from lowest byte of register s2 (0x80) is stored to byte pointed by register (s0), but the offset in the opcode is 2.

Thus the result is written to byte offset s0+2, so the result will be 0x00800180.